# Move content to separate cells from one column

Tags: vba, excel

Recently I got a big sheet to reformat. I'm not very familiar with vba but I know some stuff and tried my best I could.

It has a Column which has a phone number, some e-mail addresses and a website.

I provided you a small example of how it was, how it should be and how far I have gone.

[image]

As you can see I inserted two columns after `Id` and renamed the header to `Phone number`, `E-Mails` and `Website`. Moving the number was not really hard but I struggle at moving the E-Mail addresses and the website.

In the original sheet `Id`, `Phone number`, ... are at the top left (`Id` A1, `Phone number` B1, ...)

There are no empty rows in the file. Finding a difference between the E-Mail addresses and the website is done by looking if the cell contains an `@`. It would be great if someone could help me

Comment: Hard for us to help if we can't see code. Mind editing it in to your question? As for checking for an @ symbol, you could do something like `InStr(ADDRESS_TO_CHECK, "@")` (Instr docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I'd use something like if Instr(1,ADDRESS_TO_CHECK,"www") for the web site as your phone numbers will also pass the @ check.   Have you tried any code so far?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.  Also, it looks like your data goes [Phone Number], [email], [website].  Is it **always** going to be like that? Or could you have a mix, like [Phone Number],[website],[email],[website]?

Comment: How often do those three attributes occur per id - can one not occur at all? can there be more than one phone or website? are those three always in the order phone-email-website?

Comment: @UlliSchmid the Id 2 example looks like a absent e-mail address is acceptable but it's just my inference....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub RearangeWorkSheet2()
    Const IDColumn = 1
    Dim arrData()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RecordID As Long, lastRow As Long, x As Long, y As Long

    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ReDim arrData(3, 0)

    For x = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then
            RecordID = i
            ReDim Preserve arrData(3, i)
            arrData(0, RecordID) = Cells(x, 1)
            i = i + 1
        End If

        If IsNumeric(Left(Cells(x, 2), 3)) Then
            y = 1
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(x, 2), "@") Then
            y = 2
        Else
            y = 3
        End If

        For j = RecordID To UBound(arrData, 2)

            If IsEmpty(arrData(y, j)) Or j = UBound(arrData, 2) Then Exit For

        Next

        If Not IsEmpty(arrData(y, j)) Then
            ReDim Preserve arrData(3, i)
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
        End If

        arrData(y, j) = Cells(x, 2)
    Next

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrData, 2) + 1, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrData)

End Sub
```